# Proof of the uniform convergence of a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How is it possible to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ doesn't converge uniformly on $-1 < x < 1$, but does converge uniformly on a smaller domain $-x_0 < x < x_0$ for fixed $x_0 < 1$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is called `convergence  on every compact subset` , and it is much more common than uniform convergence (on a non-compact set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this power series was uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$, we would have :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|x|<1}\left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^k\right|=0$$

But, for any $x\in(-1,1)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ :

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^k=\frac{x^n}{1-x}$$

hence

$$\sup_{|x|<1}\left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^k\right|=+\infty$$

On the other hand, if $a\in(0,1)$ we have :

$$\sup_{|x|\le a}\left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^k\right|=\frac{a^n}{1-a}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

which proves uniform converges on $[-a,a]$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Did you employ L'Hospital's rule to get $+\infty$?

Comment: No, I didn't use it : it's enough to see that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x^n}{1-x}=+\infty$ (for any fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$).